# Possible to accessing child components in app component through angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

[image]

**app-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

**profile-info.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-info',
  templateUrl: './personal-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-info.component.scss']
})
export class PersonalInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => console.log(''));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Here i want the profile-info component need to be nested with the app component.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PersonalInfoComponent } from './personal-info/personal-info.component';     // Add this
import { WorkInfoComponent } from './work-info/work-info.component';  // Add this
import { SkillsInfoComponent } from './skills-info/skills-info.component';  // Add this
import { ProjectInfoComponent } from './project-info/project-info.component';  // Add this
import { EducationalInfoComponent } from './educational-info/educational-info.component';  // Add this
import { DeclarationInfoComponent } from './declaration-info/declaration-info.component';  // Add this

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PersonalInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    component: PersonalInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'work',
    component: WorkInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'skills',
    component: SkillsInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'project',
    component: ProjectInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'education',
    component: EducationalInfoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'declaration',
    component: DeclarationInfoComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.components.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-personal-info></app-personal-info>
```

**Expected**

When i am trying to open **"localhost:4200"** all components htmls to be displayed in the page through app component.

When i am trying to open **"localhost:4200/profile"** then only will show **"profile-info.componet"** html view. This is **working** now.

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: sharing one component with another in angular 4

Comment: just add the selector of the component to the other component

Comment: I think you mean exchanging data beetween component ? or navigating using router-link ?

Comment: @Westi-Tech refer the above screenshot.... want the html templates of other components need to be displayed in app component as well

Comment: Thanks for the edit i'm writing an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

in **app-component.ts** import the component you want to add

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonalInfoComponent } from './personal-info/personal-info.component'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

and in **app.component.html** add the selector

```
<app-personal-info></app-personal-info>
```

Comment: duplicated views update the question with what you have tried

Comment: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-personal-info></app-personal-info>"  i have added this two lines in "app.component.html"

Comment: if i am removing that my view wont changed and routing will fail. the same view will be repeated for all pages.

Comment: check your routes you have added two routes for PersonalInfoComponent thats why you're getting the duplicated routes remove the empty path from routes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the edit, it's clearer. So you are right you can achieve this with route and by creating a page with that, this is how you can do that :

- First inject all your component in your main page, which seems to be PersonalInfo, in the html template: 
  `<html>...<div class="col-md-6"><app-skills-info-component [someInput]="someData"></app-skills-info-component>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <app-other-info-component></app-other-info-component>
  </div>`

Then just add another div col-md-12 in your child component so that it takes the whole size when you are only watching the component. Your routes look good I would keep it like that.

Edit : Indeed in your app html simply use `<app-personal info></app-personal-info>`